# Can protobuf-net deserialize protected/friend fields in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, serialization, protobuf-net, silverlight-5.0

I have a complex object hierarchy that I've been wrestling with to get passed across the wire in its entirety when using Silverlight with WCF. I've tried DataContractSerializer to death and the main problem is that I'm trying to use Dictionary, with multiple cyclical references and just couldn't get it to work.

I've switched to look at protobuf-net thinking that it might be better all round to use a binary format anyway. I was hoping to be able to just do a lot of find and replace to add the ProtoMember attributes on to the properties. However a lot of the properties that were being serialized with DataMember attributes are declared as Friend (vb.net). I've found that protobuf-net throws an error when deserializing, saying

```
Attempt by method <blah> to access field <fieldname> failed.
```

I've found that setting the field to protected causes the same error, and the only way around it is to set the field to public - which is something I don't want to do. Is it possible to do this with a protected setter or similar on the property the field backs? While this would be a pain (many fields/properties and classes) it would at least solve the problem. The serialization on the back end works fine.

If this is not possible, can anyone suggest how I can get a complex object hierarchy with cyclical references that include multiple dictionaries across the wire in their complete form? I realise Silverlight adds a few constraints to this process, but hopefully someone has already succeeded with this.

Note this is Silverlight 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Silverlight: no; the runtime has a higher level of paranoia, and you just can't get at the non-public parts of other types. Even the [Silverlight `DataContractSerializer` page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) has the caveat:

> You can serialize fields and properties, provided they are publicly accessible.

My understanding is that this can't be avoided on Silverlight.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Marc, and that may have been what I was missing from the start. So just to be completely clear, the only way I'll be able to serialize something in .Net and deserialize it in Silverlight - whether using protobuff-net, DataContractSerializer or another serializer - without writing a lot of custom Onserialize/OnDeserialize type code is if every property has a public Setter (or if it's a field and not a property, that it's public). Thanks.

Comment: Also Marc, I've noticed the note on that same page you link to that says the following:

"You can apply the DataMemberAttribute to both private and public members. "

Hmmm. and to add to the confusion, there's a comment at the bottom:

"You can't serialize private variables using Silverlight 3.0 even though the documentation says you can :( "
Doesn't this conflict with the line you quote?

Comment: @hitch maybe, but they are both from the same MSDN page - so take that up with MSDN ;p Of course, while you can indeed **apply** the attribute to both public/private members, it is less clear whether it will *work* on both ;p That is possibly splitting hairs, but last time I checked DataContractSerializer on SL was public only. It is *possible* that has changed (I'd be interested if it has).

Comment: Thanks again Marc - sadly I'm more inclined to believe you than MSDN. I might do a bit of mass find and replace to make everything public just to test it out, but it looks like it could be the overall problem.

Comment: @hitch can you not try with a `[DataContract] public class Foo { [DataMember(Order=1)] public string Bar {get;set;} }` before you start hacking it all to pieces?

Comment: I was able to shelve it all in TFS then do a major Find & Replace on all private/friend/protected and change to public (purely for testing). I (obviously) no longer get the access errors, but am still having issues with the serialization/deserialization - but these problems exist if I serialize/deserialize in all .Net or serialize in .Net and deserialize in Silverlight. I use the wcf tracing to log the messages when working with DataContractSerializer, and it appeared everything was serializing correctly. I might switch back to using it with everything public and see what I find.